# Error attempting to remove layer using arcpy in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro

I am trying to remove layers from an ArcGIS Pro 1.1 project, but I receive a ValueError with the traceback of

```
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1280, in removeLayer
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.removeLayer(*gp_fixargs((remove_layer,), True)))
```

Here is code to add raster layers from a geodatabase

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*",None)
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Path/to/aprx")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for raster in rasters:
     raster = env.workspace + "\\" + raster
     aprxMap.addDataFromPath(raster)
     aprx.save()
```

This successfully adds the raster objects as layers to the current map, but when I try to remove using the following code, I get an error.

```
for raster in rasters:
         aprxMap.removeLayer(raster)
         aprx.save()
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Raster is a string, and when I have tried to write as an input string, I still receive the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The removeLayer method is expecting a Layer object not the raster name as a string.

Try using the listLayers method on the map object. Then you could identify the raster name from the layer object and check it against your list of strings.

Something like:

```
layers = aprxMap.listLayers()
for layer in layers:    
    if layer.name in rasters:
        aprxMap.removeLayer(layer)
        aprx.save()
```

Comment: This advice applies to other issues that I am having. The problem is that the python snippet one can export from the project displays the input as a string. It does not state that it is to be a pointer to an object.